# Django Store a value of selected dropdown item in database

Tags: python, django

I want to store the value of selected dropdown item and store it in database.I am unable to understand how to do this.

Here is my dropdown list:
[image: Here is my dropdown list]

Comment: Plz paste code instead of image

Comment: This is far too broad. Do you have a model? Do you have a form and a view? Have you read the tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

The question itself is a little bit too broad and it is hard to answer it without knowing what your trying to do.

It seems like that is a basic web application functionality that Django deals with its models and forms.

I suggest, first thing first, you go through Django "getting started" tutorial:

https://www.djangoproject.com/start/

However I'm going to assume now that you do know about Django basics and that for some reason you do not want to create a form for that functionality.

In that case you could add a URL to those `<a>` tags, each pointing to a view that saves a specific value, for example:

```
      def save_positive(request):
        ...
      def save_neutral(request):
        ...
      def save_negative(request):
        ...
```

But this seems like bad programming practice to say the least. I strongly recommend you check the tutorial mentioned above, or at least the forms documentation

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/

Because a form looks like the solution to your problem :)